# How can I pass extra arguments to gdb with Termdebug?

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer, debugging

While using Termdebug, occasionally it would be useful to pass extra arguments to gdb (for example, `-x`).

I've tried `:Termdebug -x <my_file> <command_to_debug>`, but that just seems to confuse the plugin. I've also tried the less convenient `:let termdebugger = "gdb -x <my_file>"` before invoking Termdebug, with similarly poor results.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `Termdebug -x ...`  works fine for me, my `script` contains only `run`, the culprit might be something in your `<my_file>` ?

Comment: Well, it works when I run `gdb -x <my_file> <command_to_debug>` outside vim, and it works when I do `source <my_file>` inside the Termdebug window (which has been my workaround), so I think the file is okay. When I try `Termdebug -x ...`, it looks like it's going into Termdebug for a split second before immediately leaving, as if gdb might be exiting immediately.

Comment: gdb argument support is added at [patch 8.0.1713](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b3623a382abc8f8e2bcfba4c1a2aa06b7578eb8d), make sure your vim is new enough.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: I turned that comment into an answer, you may accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdb argument support is added at [patch 8.0.1713](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b3623a382abc8f8e2bcfba4c1a2aa06b7578eb8d):

```
Termdebug [gdb-args] command
```

command argument support is added at [patch 8.0.1725](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/32c67ba733abcd4f2d729595fdccb2295445636a):

```
TermdebugCommand command [command-args]
```

Additionally, once TermDebug is loaded you may also pass any command from Vim to GDB since [patch 8.1.0071](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b3307b5e7e7bd3962b0d5c61a94e638564c146b0) using a function:

```
call TermDebugSendCommand(gdb-command)
```

Examples for each of those with sourcing the script as asked in the question:

```
Termdebug -x <my_file> <command_to_debug>

Termdebug <command_to_debug>
call TermDebugSendCommand('source <my_file>')
```